# symfony update user without changing password

Tags: symfony, sql-update

I'm trying to update a user in symfony without changing the password. I think it's a normal procedure which has been setup for a thousands of times before. Here, it won't work.

It results in an error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE sys_user SET password = ?, firstname = ?, locations = ?, locale = ?, timezone = ? WHERE id = ?' with params
```

I'm working with ValidationGroups, and setting up only the fristname as you can see below.

```
$userData = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

//..............

$validator = $this->get('validator');
        $this->error = $validator->validate($form, array('other'));
    }else{
        $this->error =false;
    }
     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST' && count($this->error) == 0) { 

     $form->bind($request);

    $userData->setFirstname($form->get('firstname')->getData());
    $em->persist($userData); 
    $em->flush();
```

Anyway, it results in the errro above. I'm wondering myself why it ignores my setting. I just want to update users firstname, and I don't undersand why it is trynig to update ALL the values.

EDIT: Full Error Message (frontend)

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE sys_user SET password = ?, firstname = ?, locations = ?, locale = ?, timezone = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, "testFirstname", "O:43:\"Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\":1:{s:54:\"\u0000Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\u0000_elements\";a:0:{}}", {}, "Africa\/Abidjan", 56]:
```

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Language could not be converted to string in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 1312

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error?

Comment: I added it to my question above.

Comment: Ok see my answer. Furthermore, do you really want to insert a serialised ArrayCollection for the locations param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `__toString()` function in your  `Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Language` class to convert is to the correct string for insertion in the database:

```
public function __toString() 
{
  return (string) $this->getTitle();
}
```

Or something comparable

Comment: Well it works ... . your great. Thx. 

I used to save a array for the reason that a user can have more that one location. I thought, an arrayx would be the best solution. For the reason that I have to store it right there.  Or do you think of using a seperated tabel where each value will be stored biy user id?

Comment: Yes definitely use a relation for this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html